# Getting the value of an select in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, vue-component

Well, I am trying to get the selected value of a select. This is the html code for the select:

```
 <select id="employee">
  <option v-bind:key="employee" v-for="employee of employees" v-bind:value="{id: employee.id}">{{ employee.name }}</option>
</select><br><br>
```

This is the JavaScript code where I would like to print the value of the select to the console.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('employee')[0].value)
```

Comment: why you not using a model on the <select v-model="...">?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I don't think you need to access the 0th element when calling `getElementById`.

`console.log(document.getElementById('employee').value)`.

Then, you are using vue! Make use of `v-model`.

The code below is not tested, use it as a guide only.

```
<template>    
    <select id="employee" v-model="selectedEmployee">
        <option v-bind:key="employee" v-for="employee of employees" v-bind:value="{id: employee.id}">{{ employee.name }}</option>
    </select>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: {
        selectedEmployee: null
    },
    watch: {
        selectedEmployee: (newVal) => { console.log(newVal) }
    }
}
</script>
```

If you are not aware of `v-model`, you don't know Vue.

Read about [Form Input Bindings in Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)